# Problema con las foreign keys y los valores UNIQUE

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

estamos desarrollando un proyecto para la universidad, donde se nos pide crear una especie de Ebay. Estamos con la implementación de la base de datos (con XAMPP). En el modelo tenemos dos entidades, llamadas: "DIRECCIÓN" y "PRODUCTO" (Para saber en qué dirección está cada producto). Estas dos entidades están unidas mediante una relación: "se vende" (un producto se vende en una dirección determinada).

```
CREATE TABLE direccion ( 
    calle varchar(30) NOT NULL, 
    barrio varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
    provincia varchar(2) NOT NULL, 
    region varchar(20) NOT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE producto ( 
    codigo int(8) NOT NULL, 
    vendedor varchar(16) NOT NULL, 
    calle varchar(30) NOT NULL, 
    barrio varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
    region varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
    provincia varchar(2) NOT NULL, 
    nombre_producto varchar(20) NOT NULL, ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

El caso es que cuando estábamos creando la base de datos e intentamos unir las claves externas de dirección con las de producto (calle, barrio, region y provincia), no nos dejaba, nos decía que no era el mismo tipo de datos (pero sí que lo eran). Para subsanar este error, convertimos las claves de la entidad DIRECCIÓN en claves UNIQUE. El error se solucionó.

El problema ha llegado a la hora de insertar datos en la base de datos, concretamente en la tabla DIRECCIÓN. Hemos intentado añadir dos registros:

```
INSERT INTO direccion (calle, barrio, provincia, region) 
VALUES ('Arenal 6', 'Sol', 'Madrid', 'Fondo de Bikini');

INSERT INTO direccion (calle, barrio, provincia, region) 
VALUES ('Highway', 'Gotham', 'Starcity', 'Fondo de Bikini');
```

El problema es que como la clave es UNIQUE no nos deja insertar la segunda tupla, ya que el nombre de la región de repite.

¿Alguna idea para solucionar esto?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Cómo aplicaste la función `UNIQUE` sobre tu tabla?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya siento darte la mala noticia, pero me temo que la solución pasa por revisar tu modelo ER. En la relación `se_vende` ya vincularás los productos con direcciones, por lo que no será necesario duplicar los datos de entrega en `producto`.

Además de generar redundancia de datos, si un producto lo vendes en dos direcciones diferentes, ¿duplicarías también el producto en `productos`?

El servidor no te ha dejado crear las `FK` porque los campos no los tenías indexados, no era necesario crear índices `UNIQUE`, con simples `INDEX` hubiera sido suficiente.

Al pasar del modelo ER al relacional, ha desaparecido la relación `se_vende` que debería haberse convertido en una tabla, por tener cardinalidad n:n

Espero haber respondido a tu pregunta con estas indicaciones. Si tienes más dudas, déjamelas en los comentarios y ampliaré la respuesta.

### Respuesta a los comentarios

> 1. La relación se_vende tiene cardinalidad 1:n, ya que se trata de un mercadillo online de productos usados/vintage y hemos supuesto que
>    cada producto se vende sólo en una dirección, pero en una dirección
>    pueden venderse varios productos. ¿Nuestro planteamiento sigue siendo
>    incorrecto?

En el caso de que los productos sean tangibles y únicamente se vendan una vez, entonces sí que puedes prescindir de la tabla `se_vende`. Pero no dupliques campos, simplemente guarda un `id_direccion` en `producto`. Haciéndolo así, en la misma dirección podrás entregar todos los productos que necesites.

> 2. ¿Los índices no se crean automáticamente cuando genero una clave primaria?

Si utilizas `AUTO_INCREMENT` sí, si no, pues no...

Prueba esta estructura, y me comentas qué tal:

```
CREATE TABLE direccion( 
  id_direccion int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,  
  calle varchar(30),
  barrio varchar(20), 
  provincia varchar(2), 
  region varchar(20)
  );

CREATE TABLE producto(
  id_producto int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  codigo int(8), 
  nombre_producto varchar(20),
  vendedor varchar(16),
  id_direccion int,
  FOREIGN KEY(id_direccion) REFERENCES direccion(id_direccion)
  );

INSERT INTO direccion(calle, barrio, provincia, region) 
VALUES ('Arenal 6', 'Sol', 'Madrid', 'Fondo de Bikini');

INSERT INTO direccion (calle, barrio, provincia, region) 
VALUES ('Highway', 'Gotham', 'Starcity', 'Fondo de Bikini');

INSERT INTO producto (codigo, nombre_producto, vendedor, id_direccion)
VALUES ('vinilo05','Disco de Nino Bravo','Laura',1);
```

Si quieres saber en qué dirección ha sido vendido cada producto, sólo tienes que hacer:

```
SELECT * FROM producto 
  JOIN direccion USING(id_direccion);
```

No es necesario duplicar los datos, de hecho estarías generando una redundancia.

```
1   1   0   Disco de Nino Bravo Laura   Arenal 6    Sol Ma  Fondo de Bikini
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, pero sigo teniendo algunas dudas. 

1. La relación se_vende tiene cardinalidad 1:n, ya que se trata de un mercadillo online de productos usados/vintage y hemos supuesto que cada producto se vende sólo en una dirección, pero en una dirección pueden venderse varios productos. ¿Nuestro planteamiento sigue siendo incorrecto?

2. ¿Los índices no se crean automáticamente cuando genero una clave primaria?

Comment: Acabo de modificar la respuesta para resolverte esas dudas. Ya me dices qué tal :)